# Pydantic strict mode not enforceable

Tags: python, pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, Field
class Student(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(strict=True)        
s = Student(id="1")
```

Or alternatively

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, ConfigDict, Field
class Student(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(strict=True)
    id: int        
s = Student(id="1")
```

This should return a validation error [per documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/strict_mode/#basemodel), but it does not... It simply coerces the string type to int. How can I force this?

Note: I'm using Jupyter notebook while I test this out. Slight possibility that this functionality is different on ipynb files.

Comment: For me, running both the snippets you provided gives me a ValidationError, both in a python file and a Jupyter notebook

Comment: Hmm - using SageMaker. At a loss for what's wrong. Might just need to restart the kernel. At any rate, thanks for sharing your results!